# How to convert dictionary into a specific format

Tags: python, string

I have an output which is of below format:

```
(u'Columns', [{u'Type': u'string', u'Name': u'recon_c+c'}, 
              {u'Type': u'string', u'Name': u'data'}, 
              {u'Type': u'string', u'Name': u'nui'}, 
              {u'Type': u'bigint', u'Name': u'typ'}])
```

I wanted to convert it to below format:

```
recon_c+c string,
data string,
nui string,
typ bigint
```

How to do this using python? Since I am trying for generic solution which in if I get further more keys:values also then the code can handle.

Please let me know if any solution you guys have.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Your comma requirement slightly complicates matters, but you can use `print` with its optional `sep` argument.

```
T = (u'Columns', [{u'Type': u'string', u'Name': u'recon_c+c'}, 
                  {u'Type': u'string', u'Name': u'data'}, 
                  {u'Type': u'string', u'Name': u'nui'}, 
                  {u'Type': u'bigint', u'Name': u'typ'}])

print(*(' '.join((d['Name'], d['Type'])) for d in T[1]), sep=',\n')
```

The main point to note is that you have a `tuple` and the second value of your tuple is a list of dictionaries. It is this which you need to iterate.

**Result**

```
recon_c+c string,
data string,
nui string,
typ bigint
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple for loop:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

l = (u'Columns', [{u'Type': u'string', u'Name': u'recon_c+c'}, 
{u'Type': u'string', u'Name': u'data'}, 
{u'Type': u'string', u'Name': u'nui'}, 
{u'Type': u'bigint', u'Name': u'typ'}])

print ",\n".join(['{} {}'.format(d['Name'], d['Type']) for d in l[-1]])
```

**Output:**

```
recon_c+c string,
data string,
nui string,
typ bigint
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with list comprehensions in one line:

```
myTuple = (u'Columns', [{u'Type': u'string', u'Name': u'recon_c+c'}, 
              {u'Type': u'string', u'Name': u'data'}, 
              {u'Type': u'string', u'Name': u'nui'}, 
              {u'Type': u'bigint', u'Name': u'typ'}])

myList  =  [ print (x["Name"]+" " + x["Type"]) for x in myTuple[1] ]
```

Output:

```
recon_c+c string
data string
nui string
typ bigint
```

Of course you can format print any way you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
  1 information = (
  2     u'Columns', 
  3     [
  4         {u'Type': u'string', u'Name': u'recon_c+c'},
  5         {u'Type': u'string', u'Name': u'data'}, 
  6         {u'Type': u'string', u'Name': u'nui'}, 
  7         {u'Type': u'bigint', u'Name': u'typ'}
  8     ]
  9 )
 10 
 11
 12 [print(i.get('Name'), i.get('Type')) for i in information[1]]
```

We can look at the dictionary as `information[1]` and then we can cycle through each dictionary in this list and use `dict.get()`

Using loop comprehension we could write: